# how to prove SST follows a chi-square distribution with (m−1) degrees of freedom

Tags: self-study, anova, moment-generating-function

[image]

It is easy to prove SSE/variance follows a chi-square distribution with (n-m) degrees of freedom. But how to prove SSTreament/variance follows  a chi-square distribution with (m−1) degrees of freedom? I can prove it by using moment generationg functions since I know the mgf of SSTotal/Variance and SSE/variance, then I can get the mgf of SSTreament/variance in reverse. But it is very easy to see SSE/variance follows a a chi-square distribution
[image]

[image]

but it's not easy to do it for SSTreament/Variance.

Is the moment generating function the only way to work out SSTreament/variance follows a a chi-square distribution?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: @gung  I can't transfer it to chi squaire distribution

Comment: Thank you for adding the tag. Please be sure you've read the wiki at the link, it contains our policy for this type of question. Please update the text of your question to include what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck.

Comment: Neither SSE nor SST follow a chi-square distribution, and the included image doesn't state that SST follows a chi-square distribution. It says something slightly different from that. Note that the null is assumed true, so the proof is actually quite similar to that for the SSE, but easier (because there's only one $\mu$).

Comment: @Glen_b sorry,what I mean was SSE/variance follows a chi-square distribution. I still don't know how to prove it, it is even hard for me to prove SSTotal/variance follows a n-1 df of chi-square distribution, as there are n groups of normal models, if you mix them and choose subjects from the combined sample, should the subjects follows N(u1+u2+...un, n*variance)? Someone told me it is not correct, so how am I supposed to prove  SSTotal/variance follows a n-1 df of chi-square distribution?

Comment: For SST, the distribution applies under the null (as I already mentioned and as is explicitly stated in the image), so $\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu_3...$. There's no mixing, they're all the same distribution.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for your answer. Can I say there are still mixed samples, but as all the samples have the same u and variance, so the mix of N(u,var) samples is still a N(u,var) sample?  And I still couldn't prove  SSTreament/variance follows a chi-square distribution in a intuitive way as the way to prove SSE/Variance. I mean I can use moment generating function to get the mgf of SSTreament/Variance since I know the mgf of SSTotal/Variance and SSE/Variance, but I can't see how SSTreament/variance follow a chi-square distribution in a intuitive way.

Comment: @Glen_b I have edited my original post, plz have a look

Answer (score 1):

Your proof via MGF is great actually. However, I can't think out a smarter direct proof than MGF, I can just provide a indirect method here.

Since you've already known the decomposition as following:
\begin{align}
SS = \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}(X_{ij} - \bar{X}_{..})^2 =  SSE + SST
\end{align}
and the general assumption (I changed some of your notations here):
\begin{align}
X_{ij} = \mu + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{ij}(1\le i \le k, 1\le j \le n_i)
\end{align}
where $\epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. If we are given a more specific conditions
\begin{align}
\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \cdots = \alpha_k = \alpha
\end{align}
then all $X_{ij}$ are from the same distribution $N(\mu+ \alpha, \sigma^2)$. So $SS$ is just a sample variance of size $N = \sum_{i=1}^k n_i$, which means $SS/\sigma^2 \sim \chi_{N-1}^2$. Noted here that $SST$ and $SSE$ are independent. Combined with $SSE/\sigma^2 \sim \chi_{N-k}^2$, which you've already known, and the additivity of Chi-distribution, we conclude here that $SST/\sigma^2 \sim \chi_{k-1}^2$.